# React - changing data changes output of renderToStaticMarkup() but no redraw

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm build a React app which looks a bit like this:

[image: Add a list of countries to a planet, and cities to each country]

I'm using the Flux pattern, so I have a store which contains my data. The top level panel requests data, creates the appropriate child components and passes a subset of the data down. This happens recursively, so I could have these groups infinitely nested.

As you can see, it works so far! I can click on the button to add a new Country and I get a new row. I can click on the button to add a new city to UK and I get a new row. However, when I click the button to add a new city to USA nothing happens.

I can see the data changes.

Initial state:

```
{
  "planet": {
    "name": "Earth",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "United Kingdom",
        "cities": [
          {
            "name": "London"
          },
          {
            "name": "Birmingham"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "United States of America"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After click button to add city to USA:

```
{
  "planet": {
    "name": "Earth",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "United Kingdom",
        "cities": [
          {
            "name": "London"
          },
          {
            "name": "Birmingham"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "United States of America",
        "cities": [
          {

          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can even go as far to check that the actual markup generated by React changes by calling `React.renderToStaticMarkup()` on the child elements.

Here is the markup of the USA row before:

```html
<div data="[object Object]" draggable="true" data-index="1" class="panel__group__row">
    <div class="panel__field"><label for="planet|countries|1|name">Name</label><input type="text" name="planet|countries|1|name" value="United States of America"></div>
    <div class="panel__group">
        <h4>Cities</h4>
        <div data="[object Object]" draggable="false" class="panel__group__row"><a href="">Add +</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and after:

```html
<div data="[object Object]" draggable="true" data-index="1" class="panel__group__row">
    <div class="panel__field"><label for="planet|countries|1|name">Name</label><input type="text" name="planet|countries|1|name" value="United States of America"></div>
    <div class="panel__group">
        <h4>Cities</h4>
        <div data="[object Object]" draggable="true" data-index="0" class="panel__group__row">
            <div class="panel__field"><label for="planet|countries|1|cities|0|name">Name</label><input type="text" name="planet|countries|1|cities|0|name"></div>
        </div>
        <div data="[object Object]" draggable="false" class="panel__group__row"><a href="">Add +</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However nothing it is not redrawn. Am I missing something here?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps:function(newProps){
  this.setState({ 
   promoData: newProps.promoData

  })
 },

Comment: Does any component in your chain implement componentShouldUpdate? Are you using PureRenderMixin in some component? PureRenderMixin only makes a shallow comparison, so if you only change your state a on a deeper level in your state object, it won't update.

Comment: None of my components implement `componentShouldUpdate` and I'm not using PureRenderMixin.

Answer (score 0):

Try using React.renderToString() instead of React.renderToStaticMarkup(), as the static markup render does not provide any hooks for React to render client-side for interactions.

Comment: I'm only using `renderToStaticMarkup()` to compare the markup generated, I'm not actually using that to render to the browser. Everything is rendered in the usual way.